# how to List the mounted files in local directory programmatically?

Tags: java, android, samba

I'm mounting the network using samba sharing. After mounting when I open and see the file browser the network files are shown in mounted folder. But when I call `directory.listFiles();` it's failing to show the files programmatically.

This is my code...

Main.java;

```
String mountFilePath1 = "//10.0.0.18/BeagleBoneBlack/JackSongs";
try{
            Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes("umount /data/test/ \n  chmod -R 777  /data/test/ \n mount -t cifs -o user=root,pass=guest,nounix,noserverino " + mountFilePath1 + "   /data/test/\n");
            outputStream.flush();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch(IOException e){}
```

After this when I check the /data/test directory files are shown... But when I Call

```
  File directory = new file("/data/test/");
  File[] filesList = directory.listFiles();
```

It's not showing any exception and crashing the app..
Log details are...

```
06-04 11:15:34.866    4188-4188/? E/cutils-trace﹕ Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
06-04 11:15:35.056    4188-4188/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
06-04 11:15:35.056    4188-4188/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
06-04 11:15:41.716      479-509/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '422e9b30 amiTechnologies.products.multizoneplayer/view.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-04 11:15:53.316      479-502/? E/JavaBinder﹕ !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
06-04 11:15:54.486    4558-4558/? E/cutils-trace﹕ Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
06-04 11:15:54.616    4558-4558/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
06-04 11:15:54.616    4558-4558/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
06-04 11:15:55.326      891-891/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
06-04 11:15:55.326      891-891/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
06-04 11:15:57.036    4733-4733/? E/cutils-trace﹕ Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-04 11:15:57.176    4733-4733/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
06-04 11:15:57.176    4733-4733/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
```